# Activate comments in PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, ghostscript, comments

I am generating PDF files with `pdflatex` and I would like my PDF to allow comments/annotations (without having to use Acrobat Professional to write the comments). `pdflatex` cannot enable comments in PDF files. Is there a free software that can activate this functionality on existing PDF files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If with "activate this functionality" you mean make it available in Adobe Acrobat Reader, then the answer is no, there is not such software. See an answer I wrote for a similiar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/183754/pdf-commented-in-foxit-reader-can-not-be-commented-in-adobe-reader-anymore).

Comment: OK. Thank you... Do you know free software that can add annotations then?

Comment: You can try with PDFEdit (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfedit/) but I have not used it myself... There might be other though. There is a comparison page here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_notetaking_software.

Comment: PDFStudio can add annotations for example, but it's paid...

Comment: Amyuni PDF Creator also (I work for them actually) but you specified "Free", that's why I did not mention it before.

Comment: PDFEDit works fine, thanks. Foxit is also a good one for Windows actually.

Comment: @yms: unfortunately your answer above is probably well-intended, but wrong nevertheless. Of course Acrobat Reader can display all comments that may be part of a PDF file.

Comment: @pipitas I think what Raphink meant is that he wants to generate a pdf  file such that he can add new annotations when the file is used in Acrobat Reader. So I think my answer is not wrong.

Comment: @yms: my apologies to you for that misunderstanding and calling your answer "wrong". Your answer was of course correct then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ghostscript to add annotations to a PDF file. Is that free enough for you? Try something like this:

```
 gs \
   -o commented-output.pdf \
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -c "[ /Rect [ 75 400 175 550 ] \
         /Open true \
         /Title (Important note) \
         /Contents (This document is a preliminary version\!) \
         /Color [1 0 0] \
         /ANN pdfmark" \
   -f uncommmented-input.pdf
```

If you want to know more about this method, you need to read up about the `pdfmark` operator in PostScript/PDF. For acquiring first familiarity with pdfmark, see first here:

- http://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/pdfmark_primer.pdf ,

then here:

- http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/pdf_creation_apis_and_specs/pdfmarkReference.pdf

Comment: My original question was actually how to activate comments in the PDF file so people using standard Acrobat Reader could comment. If I had to add comments in the original PDF, I could do so directly with LaTeX. On the other hands, since my goal is to let (mainly non-tech) users comments on my PDFs, I think I'm just going to tell them to use FoxitReader.

Comment: @Raphink: Oh, sorry... in that case I misread your question.

Comment: @Raphink: BTW, FoxitReaderPortable (from http://portableapps.com/ ) works well for me even inside Wine on Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick...

Comment: Actually, I'm using FoxitReader in wine, and it works fine, too (on Natty).

Answer (score 0):

I used [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer). Annotation and highlighting was free in that time.
There are interesting online services for annotation like [A.nnotate](http://a.nnotate.com/) or [Crocodoc](http://crocodoc.com/).
Here is an [article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/2-ways-annotate-pdf-files-online/) about other possibilities.

Comment: I've read about A.nnotate. I'm not sure about using an online service if I don't have to. The goal is collaboration though, and with possibly several reviewers and many versions of the same document. Would A.nnotate help with that?

Comment: [Here](http://a.nnotate.com/collaboration.html) is described the possibility of collaboration.

Comment: I found [yet another](http://www.mendeley.com/blog/progress-update/mendeley-v0-9-6-1-released/) interesting software that supports collaborative pdf annotation.

Comment: Just having a look at A.nnotate and crocodoc. A.nnotate has some free credits to upload files, but I need to upload a new version everyday, of up to 300 pages, so that won't do. Crocodoc looks nicer (to my taste at least) and has a free API which allows to upload new documents. The only thing I'd like to see in both is the ability to replace a document with a new version. From what I see, you have to create a shared folder and upload new documents in it (in crocodoc at least).

Comment: Other possibility is to convert the pdf file into images. In Linux you can use `pdftk file.pdf burst; for i in pg*.pdf; do convert -density 300 "$i" "${i%.*}.jpg"; done` You can upload the images to some image hosting service (like **Flickr**) there is possibility to write comments to images. But your images won't be editable. Or you can convert (OCR) it to html and use **Diigo**

Comment: @xralf: I don't think commenting on images on Flickr is much nicer than directly on PDF on Crocodoc. And OCR wouldn't help to comment on page layout... Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

You can add annotations in [evince](https://projects.gnome.org/evince/). You do this by going to the panel on the left in evince (press F9 if you don't have one) and selecting annotations. To add an annotation you then click the add button and then the pencil button. Be warned though, you can't delete annotations.